# How to get a part of a datastring from clicking a listview-item

Tags: android, string, listview, trim

I have a variable called current which holds the last clicked listview item data. The id of this data is to be used to query the db again for movies taht are similar.

The problem that current = id=17985, title=the matrix, year=1999 when all i need is the actual id-number. I have tried to use substring to only use the correct places of the string. This works for the matrix since its id is exactly 5 digits long, but as soon as i try to click  movie with higher/lower amount of digits in its id of course it trips up.

String id = current.substring(4,9).trim().toString(); does not work for all movies.

Heres some code:

// search method: this is necessary cause this is the method thats first used and where the variable current is set. This is also the only method using three lines for getting data - id, title and year.

```
 protected void search() {
        data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        EditText searchstring = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchstring);
        String query = searchstring.getText().toString().replace(' ', '+');
        String text;

        text = searchquery(query);
        try {
            JSONObject res = new JSONObject(text);

            JSONArray jsonArray = res.getJSONArray("movies");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                item = new HashMap<String, String>(2);
                item.put("id",jsonObject.getString("id"));
                item.put("title",jsonObject.getString("title"));
                item.put("year", jsonObject.getString("year"));
                data.add(item);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }                   

        aa = new SimpleAdapter(SearchTab.this, data,
                R.layout.mylistview,
                new String[] {"title", "year"},
                new int[] {R.id.text1,
                R.id.text2});
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lv.setAdapter(aa);
        lv.setDividerHeight(5); 

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

                Map<String, String> s = data.get((int) id);
                current = s.toString();
            }});
    }
```

// similar method: this tries to build a list from the fetched data from "current"-string. As you can see i try to use 4,9 to only get right numbers, but this fails with others. Best would be to only to be ble to get the ID which I cant seem to do. The toast is just to see what is beeing fetched, much like a system out print.

```
 protected void similar() {
        data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        String id = current.substring(4,9).trim().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String text;

        text = similarquery(id);
        try {
            JSONObject res = new JSONObject(text);

            JSONArray jsonArray = res.getJSONArray("movies");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                item = new HashMap<String, String>(2);
                item.put("title",jsonObject.getString("title"));
                item.put("year", jsonObject.getString("year"));
                data.add(item);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }                   

        aa = new SimpleAdapter(SearchTab.this, data,
                R.layout.mylistview2,
                new String[] {"title", "year"},
                new int[] {R.id.text1,
                R.id.text2});
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lv.setAdapter(aa);
        lv.setDividerHeight(5); 

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `current.split(",")[0].split("=")[1]`

edit - assuming of course that id is always the first in the comma separated list and will always be a name value pair delimited by '='

Comment: I tried ur solution too, it was neat, but also here the next click (2nd) displays nithing in the listview, but the toast is still toasting the id. Do you know why?

Comment: I have two toasts now just to see what happens. With your solution its ok at the 1st click and gives current(non-edit) is = {id=12897, year=1999, title=The Matrix} and in the next click its only {year=2003, title=The Matrix Reloaded}. With your edited current i get at first click 12897 (which is matrix id) but next click i get 2003 which is Reloadeds year. Why???

Comment: OMG NEVERMIND... Had one BIG miss. :)) much love for your help though <3

Answer (score 1):

If you want to solve it via substring then you shouldn't use a predefined `.substring(4,9)`. Use something like that:

```
String item = "id=17985, title=the matrix, year=1999";
String id = item.substring(item.indexOf("id=") + 3, item.indexOf(" ", item.indexOf("id=") + 3) - 1);
System.out.println("Your ID is: " + id);
// Works also for "test=asdf, id=17985, title=the matrix, year=1999"
```

It gets the String between "id=" and the next " " (space).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for input, i tried to use this and it was OK at the first search, it found the id and could use it in the query, only the next time i clicked i got "ear=2003" which it did with my pre-destinied solution as well. This means I guess that the current just keeps iterating til the year-part, so I tried to set current = "" after listview is set but did not get it right

Comment: Actually it Toasts the actual year of the movie at the 2nd click. So somehow the id is changing

Comment: That sounds a bit unpossible because the substring starts always after "id=" (`item.indexOf("id=")`). If there isn'n a "id=" you should get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Please post the content of your `current` before you try to fetch the id.

Comment: I tried a couple of ways now but my holder for the id is changing somehow. I dont get IndexOutOfBoundsException, the toast says ear=2003 that is year=2003. The content of current is = {id=12897, year=1999, title=The Matrix} the first time i hit similar-button. The second time i only get = {year=2003, title=The Matrix Reloaded}

Comment: OMG NEVERMIND. Had one BIG miss. :)) much love for your help though <3